# How to implement my own system call without recompiling the Linux kernel?

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, system-calls

I want to implementing my own system call. (See below link)

http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/html_single/Implement-Sys-Call-Linux-2.6-i386/

But adding new system call requires kernel compilation.

How to implement my own system call without recompiling the Linux kernel?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can't.

Without recompiling the kernel, all you can do is build and load kernel modules, and kernel modules cannot add new system calls.

Comment: Well that was short and sweet.

Comment: Well, technically, subject to space and such, with a kernel module, you could patch your own system call into the existing system call table. But it's messy, unreliable and definitely not a good idea.

Comment: Well technically an IOCTL is a system call. So, when you can use it to wrap your data and talk across user and kernel land, why would you add a new system call?

Comment: @Ash: Right — you can certainly add functionality to **existing** function calls, like `ioctl()`, but you cannot add entirely new system calls.

Answer (score 4):

Sure, you can.

In short, you'll need to patch the running kernel.

There are at least 2 ways to add a new syscall:

1. Expand the existing system call tables (`sys_call_table` and `ia32_sys_call_table`) and patch system call limit check instruction (usally `cmp` on x86) at any of the system call entries (`system_call`, `ia32_system_all` etc...)
2. Copy existing system call tables, expand them as needed, patch system call dispatch instruction (usally `call` on x86) to point to table's copy and patch system call limit check instruction at any of the system call entries.

See this anwers for details:

[Implementing Linux System Call using LKM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12623066/implementing-linux-system-call-using-lkm)

[How do 32-bit applications make system calls on 64-bit Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3305350/how-do-32-bit-applications-make-system-calls-on-64-bit-linux)

:)

Comment: The method you're describing is incredibly ugly and unsafe — unless you are incredibly careful about it, there is a significant chance that it will crash the machine when loaded. Under no circumstances would I consider using a module that did that on a production system.

Comment: As for the method, it works but implementation matters, you are right. Correct implementation requires strong skills and this task not for suckers :)